# What kind of presentation program Gregg Pollack uses in Rails for Zombies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, presentation

What kind of presentation program Gregg Pollack uses in Rails for Zombies video? They are very awesome and handy. http://images2.mytube.uz//images143/104764.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use Keynote (sometimes Powerpoint) and then they build a bit on top of it. 
They have a pretty thorough screencasting guide [here](https://www.codeschool.com/screencasting).

Comment: Boom, I couldn't have said it better myself, thanks Amir.  All Keynote, and that screencasting guide says it all.

Comment: Man, I can't believe you replied to the answer I gave. This rocks! I'm your biggest fan in the middle east :P

Comment: Edit: new URL is https://www.codeschool.com/screencasting